# Scatter homogenous list of values to PyTorch tensor

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

Consider the following list:

```
[[3], [1, 2], [4], [0], [2]]
```

And zeros tensor of size `(5, 5)`

I want to fill these indices according to their index in the list to the tensor with 1.

So, the expected output should be:

```
tensor([[0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.]])
```

What happened above is this:

at the index `[0, 3]` put `1` (the case for the first element in my list).

---

A very similar case is achievable through using [`Tensor.scatter_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.scatter_). However, since it takes a tensor as the argument (`index`); you cannot create a tensor from a list if it contains a sub-list with a different size than the other elements, which is the case with `[1, 2]` in my list *(this is actually the problem)*.

The `scatter` method could be used if the list is all of same size as the following:

```
tensor.scatter_(1, torch.tensor(index), 1)
```

---

*Numpy solutions are acceptable*

Comment: is it reasonable making with numpy?

Comment: Sure, very reasonable.

Comment: let me try something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by modifying your index list to have the same number of indices in each element.

```
max_length = max([len(l) for l in index])
index = [l + l[-1:] * (max_length - len(l)) for l in index]
```

This code will repeat the last element of each sub-list until they are all the same size. You can then pass it to the `scatter_` function as you wrote in your question.